# Merge dfs based on specific conditions and reduce the execution time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below

df1:

```
ID     Age_days    N_30     N_31_90          
1      201         60       15                      
2      20          0        15                      
3      800         0        0                       
4      100         0        0                       
5      600         0        6
```

df2:

```
ID     Salary      Speed    Group         
1      2000        60       A                      
2      600         0        C                           
3      9000        0        B                         
4      1000        0        D                          
5      4000        0        A                
6      8000        0        A
```

Where I would like to merge the salary column of df2 with df1 based on the ID column values.

Expected Output:

```
ID     Age_days    N_30     N_31_90   Salary       
1      201         60       15        2000               
2      20          0        15        600                    
3      800         0        0         9000                  
4      100         0        0         1000                 
5      600         0        6         8000
```

I tried the below code

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['ID', 'Speed']], on='ID')
```

Getting the expected output. Is there any other method where my execution time can be reduced

Comment: How much did it take? How many rows in the DataFrames?

Comment: @MaxPierini it is around 85K rows

Comment: And how much did `merge` take?

Comment: @MaxPierini did not take much time. But I would like to know any other methods.

Comment: AFAIK `merge` is best way to do this, any other solution would be slower, you could try to implement your own with `Parallel` from `joblib`